# MVVM computed properties

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Whats the recommended way of dealing with computed properties that are basically string formatting ? In the View or in the ViewModel? At the moment I've got this in the view:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text="Free Memory (KB): " />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text="{Binding MemoryRemain}" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text=" / " />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text="{Binding MemoryTotal}" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text=" (" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text="{Binding MemoryRemainPercent}" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FootnoteTextStyle}" Text="%)" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is it better to put this in the viewmodel as a computed property of type string and then just have a single TextBlock bound to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also kinda possible to use string.format in XAML. I suppose you could rewrite your xaml to this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="Free Memory (KB): {0} / {1} ({2}%)">
                <Binding Path="MemoryRemain" />
                <Binding Path="MemoryTotal" />
                <Binding Path="MemoryRemainPercent" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

IMO, it's a bit cleaner, because you see the string as a whole, as you would in code. I also agree with slugster and Myles J that the formatting should be done by the view.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment by slugster "formatting any values should be done by the View".  I would just add that you could always write a custom converter to take care of the formatting side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I generally create additional properties and put the formatting in the getters in the view model.  Its the model of the view and concerned with how something is displayed.  I suppose it also makes the display format testable.

Comment: But the VM should be view agnostic - it knows it is presenting a string to the UI, but has no idea **how** that string is going to be shown. Construction of text can be done in the VM, but formatting any values should be done by the View. (i.e. the VM holds the value 3.1415926, it doesn't know that the View is only going to show 3.14).

Comment: Interesting, I've always thought the view model is sort of the non visual representation of the view and the view is simply showing the data.

Comment: yeah there is a whole bunch of interpretations out there about what should be in the VM when using MVVM. Even things like enum->colors can be handled exclusively in the View by using a converter. Personally i restrict it even further by exposing the VM as an interface to the View, so MyView receives a IMyViewModel.